# iOS Bluetooth - How to know when pairing is done

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am trying to securely connect to a bluetooth device. I connect using CBCentralManager, which causes a popup to appear. I need a callback to let me know when it's pairing/bonding has completed, so that I can start sending commands to my device.

Is there a call back to let me know when pairing is done?

Comment: have a peek at the delegate method `centralManager(central:didConnect:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate#

Comment: @adrian I'm afraid that did connect gets hit right when the pairing prompt appears. I'll dig further into the documentation. Hopefully I find something.

Comment: @Yogurt Did you manage to fix that? can you help me with that please?

Comment: @Sudhanshu No unfortunately.