# How do I initiate pairing with a BLE peripheral that uses unprotected ATT attributes?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are developing an iOS app that must pair (and bond) with a BLE peripheral before our app can proceed with other steps. From what I understand Apple wants accessories to follow this flow to initiate pairing:

1. iOS device connects to accessory
2. iOS device attempts to access an attribute that requires special permissions (e.g. authenticated connection or encrypted connection)
3. Accessory rejects the attribute access with an “Insufficient Authentication” error code
4. iOS realizes it needs to initiate pairing, so it generates a pairing popup that allows the user to initiate it

The problem is that the firmware on our BLE peripheral can not be altered. All of its BLE attributes are unprotected and do not require an encrypted or authenticated connection to access these attributes. So in this case, how can we get iOS to generate the pairing popup so that the user will have the ability to pair?

I realize that my question is related to [How to bond/pair to a bluetooth LE device programmatically in swift Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41690946/4347877), but it differs in that we can not change the permissions used by the characteristics of our BLE peripheral. We have no control over the firmware.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your device doesn't require encryption then iOS will not bother with paring/bonding since there is no need for the keys that would be exchanged. it just makes life more complicated for everyone (particularly the user) for no purpose. There's nothing you can do.

Comment: Whenever you design a BLE peripheral, you must always keep in mind with what platforms it will be used with, so you don't end up with an incompatible product. Anyway, the peripheral can send an SMP Security Request as another option to initiate pairing.